# Axis on Google Charts - Bar

Tags: google-visualization

I have created a Bar Chart using Google Charts. I am not able to get the X axis for the Bar Chart even though I am getting the axis labels. I tried using baseline but to no effect.

**I have added an image of what I exactly want.
**
[Please refer to the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPVOh.png)
Could someone please let me know how I could enable X axis for Bar Chart.

I am also facing a similar issue with Y axis Column charts.

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: going to need more information, code would help. which chart are you using? _Material_ --> `google.charts.Bar` or _Core_ --> `google.visualization.BarChart` -- and please clarify _not able to get the X axis_ --> it doesn't appear, you can't set the values, ...?

Comment: I have tried using both Material charts and Core charts. When I say not able to get the X axis, I meant I am not able to get the horizontal X axis. I am getting the axis values fine.

Link for JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqed1u3k/

Comment: I have also added an image to my original post.

Comment: looks like there isn't enough room to display the labels, you can adjust the size of the `chartArea` -- in this case, reduce `chartArea.height` -- [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37569822/5090771) for an example

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat. My problem is not with the axis labels, but the missing axis line itself. I need a horizontal and vertical axis, but am getting only the vertical axis not the horizontal axis. I tried achieving this using gridlines with count set to 1, but if am correct gridlines only work properly with continous data and my graph is with discrete data so I can not use gridlines either.

Comment: that is correct, need a continuous axis -- is there a reason you can't switch?