# How to set Google Chart height based on number of rows?

Tags: javascript, charts, asp.net-core, google-visualization

I have a Google stacked bar chart that pulls data from a database and draws charts based on said data.  I was able to search around and find a way to dynamically set the height based on the number of rows - but for one of my search filters, the charts look way off.

The code is below and works for 4 out of 5 of my filters, but in the 5th filter the number of rows becomes much larger (around 40-50).

Code:

```
            var paddingHeight = 40;
            var rowHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 50;
            var chartHeight = rowHeight + paddingHeight;

            var options = {
                titlePosition: 'none',
                width: 1400,
                height: chartHeight,
                legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
                bar: { groupWidth: '50%' },
                isStacked: true,
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Business Hours (excluding weekends & holidays)'
                },
                colors: ['#0066ff', '#33cc33', '#ffcc00', '#ff0000'],
                annotations: {
                    alwaysOutside: true,
                    textStyle: {
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Produces the following results.  This first image is what 4 of my 5 filters looks like.

[image: Image 1]

The second image is the one in question that shows I'm clearly doing something wrong.

[image: Image 2]

What is the cause of this and how can I resolve it?

Edit: I suspect my issue is one of the following:
Either my data rows are not being counted correctly as I refresh the page with the latest search parameters or I have a problem with how my divs are set up and interacting with each other.  I've tried adjusting the math behind the `chartHeight` and removing the padding and it seems to have the same effect either way.  Am I on the right track or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

need to set options for both `height` and `chartArea.height`

here, recommend using `rowHeight` for `chartArea.height`

```
        var paddingHeight = 40;
        var rowHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 50;
        var chartHeight = rowHeight + paddingHeight;

        var options = {
            titlePosition: 'none',
            width: 1400,

            height: chartHeight,
            chartArea: {
              height: rowHeight,
            },

            legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
            bar: { groupWidth: '50%' },
            isStacked: true,
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Business Hours (excluding weekends & holidays)'
            },
            colors: ['#0066ff', '#33cc33', '#ffcc00', '#ff0000'],
            annotations: {
                alwaysOutside: true,
                textStyle: {
                    color: '#000000'
                }
            }
        }
```

you'll want to leave some room for the legend, y-axis, etc...

`chartArea` has the following properties

`top`
`left`
`height`
`width`

you'll want to set `top` to `20` or something if legend is on top

Comment: hope this helps, [here is a working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37569822/5090771) to demonstrate...

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the quick response!  Seems like I was close but had no idea about the chartArea option so thank you for that!  Looks like I can do something similar with `bottom` to get my numbers to show up too so that's nice.

I also noticed how in my screenshots, the second chart staggers the legend to a second line - is there a way to fix that so that it's consistently 1 line and not broken up into 2 lines?

Comment: If possible, can you please explain briefly what was happening to my chart when setting the height but not the chartArea height?  I ask because if I didn't have a set of data that was large enough to discover this issue, I would have been handling this the wrong way and would have probably ran into trouble down the line.

Comment: although the `height` was being set, `chartArea.height` was using some default number -- e.g. -- if the overall `height` is `100` and you want to leave `20` each for the legend and y-axis at the bottom, then you would set --> `height: 100`, `chartArea.height: 60`, `chartArea.top: 20` -- which leaves `20` for the bottom by default -- note: there is no property for `bottom` -- as for legend lines, just needs to be wide enough or try using option for `legend.maxLines: 1`

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.  That's odd that you say there's no bottom.  I was able to add a `bottom: 60` to my chartArea and now the bottom row (numbers + axis label) show up.  Maybe that's new?  I'll give the maxLines a go.  The last time I tried something like that it ended up leaving me with arrows to scroll left and right and didn't show them all so I will see what that does, thanks again!

Comment: cool -- `bottom` isn't listed in the configuration options -- but it was added with [version 43](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#october-2-2015), along with `right`...